# Implementing Redux to React to return JSON data from provided endpoint

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, redux, react-redux

HW assignment is asking us to use React, Redux, and Redux-Thunk to return JSON data from a provided endpoint called `url` in an excel type table.

I was able to return the appropriate data in a table by JUST using React Hooks and Axios as you'll see in the codesandbox.

[CODE DEMO](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-codesandbox-c261z?fontsize=14)

What could be a simple way to implement Redux and Thunk into this mix?

My thinking could be to:

- Set up store.js for Redux to create store and initialize state
- Create Action folder => create dataActions.js => write a action function that has the useEffect method with the Axios get request
- Create Reducer folder => create dataReducer.js => write a reducer that initializes state => export default function that has a switch statement that returns the state of the data retrieved and then a default statement for anything else

All this extraneous adding of Redux/Thunk is to see if I'm able to connect all the parts together, even though we don't need it for this particular assignment. Not sure how to incorporate these 2 on top of the solution.

I'd appreciate any pointers or tips to get me on the right track.

Comment: Hooks are for React, Redux is another tool. A redux action is the right place to fetch, so just do that, fetch with axios. The redux-thunk middleware will make it possible to create a function action that deals with the axios promise and _dispatches_ a simple Redux action with the data, which a reducer should handle to store that data.

Comment: Would separating something like this into a `dataActions.js` make sense? I think my main trouble is separating everything.

Comment: @EmileBergeron https://imgur.com/Btt6Nmf

Comment: You can put your actions wherever you like, ideally, yes, in another file so they're isolated from your rendering logic.

Comment: Take a look at [`react-redux`](https://redux.js.org/basics/usage-with-react) to see how to connect your Redux store to your React components.

Answer (score 2):

Essentially to convert your sample to use Redux you should:

1. Create [reducer](https://redux.js.org/basics/reducers) which will accept actions and modify store.

   Here is example

   ```
   const initalState = {
       usersData: [],
       isLoading: false,
       isError: false,
       errorMsg: ""
   };

   function reducer(state = initalState, action) {
       switch (action.type) {
           case "REQUEST_USERS_DATA":
               return {
                   ...state,
                   isLoading: true,
                   isError: false,
                   errorMsg: ""
              };
           case "RECEIVE_USERS_DATA":
               return {
                   ...state,
                   usersData: action.usersData,
                   isLoading: false,
                   isError: action.isError,
                   errorMsg: action.errorMsg
               };
           default:
               return state;
        }
   }
   ```
2. Create [action creator](https://redux.js.org/basics/actions) for requesting users data

   ```
   export const requestUsers = url => async dispatch => {
       dispatch({
           type: "REQUEST_USERS_DATA"
       });
       try {
           const json = await axios.get(url);
           dispatch({
               type: "RECEIVE_USERS_DATA",
               usersData: json.data,
               isError: false,
               errorMsg: ""
           });
       } catch (e) {
           dispatch({
               type: "RECEIVE_USERS_DATA",
               usersData: [],
               isError: true,
               errorMsg: e
           });
       }
   };
   ```

   Action creator will dispatch actions to reducer and also request data using axios.
3. Create store with [thunk middleware](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk) to be able to dispatch functions as actions.

   ```
   export const store = createStore(reducer, applyMiddleware(thunkMiddleware));
   ```
4. Use `<Provider store={store}>` in `App` component to provide store to all children.
5. Extract rendering logic to separate component, say `TableComponent` which will dispatch actions and receive data from Redux. Redux now supports [it own hooks](https://react-redux.js.org/api/hooks), so you can use `useSelector` and `useDispatch` to access Redux in hooks style.

   ```
   const { usersData, isError, isLoading, errorMsg } = useSelector(
       state => state
   );
   const dispatch = useDispatch();
   ```

And here is [working sample](https://codesandbox.io/s/so56943905-fknjw).

Comment: A good standard for actions is [_redux-actions_](https://github.com/redux-utilities/redux-actions) and [_redux-thunk-actions_](https://github.com/machadogj/redux-thunk-actions) to avoid creating these async actions manually.

Comment: @EmileBergeron for the hw, they wanted unit testing through Jest, what do you think `sufficient unit testing` would amount to? This question is for anyone too

Comment: and wouldn't using both redux-thunk-actions and axios be unnecessary?

Comment: @mph85 axios is an HTTP client while redux-thunk-action wraps the logic around redux async action management (`SUCCEED`, `FAILED`, `ENDED` action types). Completely different libraries.